# Cocoa MacOS - Easiest way to record microphone input and save as mp3

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, recording

I'm looking for an easy way to record the input from my macbook mic and save it as a mp3 file.

I tried some apple examples with CoreAudio, but they are very sophisticated (plus the recording quality was not really good).

What I'm looking for is something simple like AVAudioSession in iOS.

Is there a library or something like AVAudioSession for MacOS or do I have to take the hard way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What did you do with CoreAudio? As far as I know CoreAudio on osx does not have an mp3 encoder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `.mp3` is a supported output file format for any of the Apple recording APIs. Otherwise, [`AVAudioRecorder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/) is probably your best bet:

> An instance of the `AVAudioRecorder` class, called an audio recorder, provides audio recording capability in your application. Using an audio recorder you can:
>
> • Record until the user stops the recording
>
> • Record for a specified duration
>
> • Pause and resume a recording
>
> • Obtain input audio-level data that you can use to provide level metering
>
> In iOS, the audio being recorded comes from the device connected by the user—built-in microphone or headset microphone, for example. In OS X, the audio comes from the system’s default audio input device as set by a user in System Preferences.
>
> The `AVAudioRecorder` class is intended to allow you to make audio recordings with very little programming overhead.

Comment: I want to send the microphone data over network. Is that possible with `AVAudioRecorder `?

Comment: `AVAudioRecorder` is meant for recording audio data to a file. I would suggest using `AVAudioEngine` to read audio from the microphone and then encoding it for the network.